# sudo: command not found

Tags: apache2, sudo

I'm new to this. I'm trying to install apache2 on an Ubuntu 15.04 server.
Running as root.

But when giving the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
root@dev:~# whoami
root

root@dev:~# apt-cache policy sudo
N: Unable to locate package sudo

root@dev:~# apt-get install sudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package sudo

root@dev:~# apt-cache policy sudo
N: Unable to locate package sudo

root@dev:~# sudo apt-get install apache2
-bash: sudo: command not found

root@dev:~# apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

**EDIT**:

Ran; apt-get update and then tried again. Worked!

Comment: Does su work instead of sudo?

Comment: Are you running as root? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `whoami` and `apt-cache policy sudo`.

Comment: `which sudo` shows anything? If not please add results from `more /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: @Rinzwind - I have a question. OP says that he is running as root right? So, he can use apt-get install sudo to install it, can't he?

Comment: @muru Yes, whoami outputs root. The other returns; N: Unable to locate package sudo. So I guess it isn't installed yet. Going to look into that now. As I said, I'm new to this.

Comment: @Raphael sure but the "$" in front of the command says otherwise. If the "$" is correct and it is root I doubt he is using Ubuntu. This what he says here would happen on -debian-: no sudo install there and it uses root.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Oh! right.

Comment: @Rinzwind Someone else edited the "$" inside my post, not sure why..

Comment: @Hees1989 - try running apt-get install su

Comment: @Raphael Tried it, it keeps returning; 'E: Unable to locate package su'

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but if you are running as root, what purpose does sudo serve? Regardless are you connected to the internet? what is the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @ElderGeek You're right, read that now. As I said, I'm new to this. Got it working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are root you shouldn't need `sudo` to run the command. Try running the commands without `sudo` as in `apt-get install apache2` for example.

Source: experience

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't installed? Open your package manager and install the sudo package.

taken from [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23572/bash-sudo-command-not-found) on unix & Linux.