# sudo: apt: command not found

Tags: command-line, apt

My current command line results:

```
localhost / # whoami
root
localhost / # pwd
/
localhost / # sl
bash: sl: command not found
localhost / # sudo apt install sl
sudo: apt: command not found
localhost / #
```

I tried to run `sl` command, but I got this error message.

```
bash: sl: command not found.
```

I tried to run `sudo apt install sl` but I got this error message:

```
sudo: apt: command not found.
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of text, add the text to your question.   You haven't told us what Ubuntu (or OS) release you are using?  I'd suggest `whereis apt` to see if it's present, and then check your $PATH

Comment: Which distribution is this?

Comment: Why are you using sudo at a root prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695492/sudo-command-not-found)

Comment: You have tagged `kali` - do you have kali or katoolin installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're root, you should not use `sudo` in your command. Sudo is a way of temporarily giving yourself root permissions, which you don't need in this scenario since you're already root. Just try `apt install sl`.

If that doesn't work, I would need more details to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the root permissions. I ran the command apt install sl. My return was, -bash: apt: command not found. I ran $PATH next and this was the return, -bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin: No such file or directory