# Connection failed

Tags: networking

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS but I'm unable to connect to any sort of network.
It always says "network failed. Activation of network connection failed"
I read lots of solutions in this platform and elsewhere but none works for me.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart or 
# sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop 
# sudo /etc/init.d/networking start  
# sudo systemctl restart networking
```

I get error message: sudo command... not found

At the moment, I don't have access to wired internet
What can I do?

Comment: If the `sudo` command is not found, that's a MUCH more important problem than networking. It suggests a catastrophe has occurred. Can you enlighten us on what might have happened to destroy/delete/move your `sudo` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo: apt: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105269/sudo-apt-command-not-found)

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked for me. I had to do s fresh installation and get a newer wifi adapter. Thank you all for your efforts